# GeoTIFF is stretched sideway when translating CRS to EPSG:4326 from EPSG:32654

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, rasterio

I want to convert a GeoTIFF's coordinate reference system to EPSG:4326 from EPSG:32654. But the output image is stretched to the side.

I have tried two different methods (gdalwarp and rasterio), but the result is the same.

Why does this happen? If you know of a solution, I would like to know how to solve this problem.

This is the command I used.

```bsh
gdalwarp -s_srs epsg:32654 -t_srs epsg:4326 source.tif target.tif
```

Here is my GeoTIFF file EPSG:32654 (before conversion) and its gdalinfo.
[image]

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: source.tif
Size is 9105, 5977
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 54N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",141],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32654"]]
Origin = (286156.478620000008959,3945902.046580000314862)
Pixel Size = (0.018810000000000,-0.018810000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=pix4dmapper
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  286156.479, 3945902.047) (138d38'18.28"E, 35d38' 1.71"N)
Lower Left  (  286156.479, 3945789.619) (138d38'18.39"E, 35d37'58.06"N)
Upper Right (  286327.744, 3945902.047) (138d38'25.09"E, 35d38' 1.84"N)
Lower Right (  286327.744, 3945789.619) (138d38'25.20"E, 35d37'58.20"N)
Center      (  286242.111, 3945845.833) (138d38'21.74"E, 35d37'59.95"N)
Band 1 Block=9105x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=-10000
Band 2 Block=9105x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=-10000
Band 3 Block=9105x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=-10000
Band 4 Block=9105x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  NoData Value=-10000
```

Here is my GeoTiff file epsg:4326 (after conversion) and its gdalinfo.
[image]

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: target.tif
Size is 9709, 5310
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (138.638412488183292,35.633844968775641)
Pixel Size = (0.000000197720465,-0.000000197720465)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=pix4dmapper
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 138.6384125,  35.6338450) (138d38'18.28"E, 35d38' 1.84"N)
Lower Left  ( 138.6384125,  35.6327951) (138d38'18.28"E, 35d37'58.06"N)
Upper Right ( 138.6403322,  35.6338450) (138d38'25.20"E, 35d38' 1.84"N)
Lower Right ( 138.6403322,  35.6327951) (138d38'25.20"E, 35d37'58.06"N)
Center      ( 138.6393723,  35.6333200) (138d38'21.74"E, 35d37'59.95"N)
Band 1 Block=9709x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 2 Block=9709x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 3 Block=9709x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 4 Block=9709x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

Comment: And what makes you think that this is not intentional behavior? Also rasterio and gdalwarp are the same methods.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you are looking the image with a non-geospatial viewer that shows pixels as pixels. The EPSG:4326 version has pixels which are square in degrees `Pixel Size = (0.000000197720465,-0.000000197720465)`. But the image is from 35.63 degrees N and one degree in meters is not as long along the latitude than along the longitude. Only on top of the Equator one degree is as long in both directions.

Calculator at http://www.csgnetwork.com/degreelenllavcalc.html gives results:

```
Length Of A Degree Of Latitude In Meters   110952.13
Length Of A Degree Of Longitude In Meters   90582.94
```

With your image the viewer is stretching 90582 ground units in west-east direction into 110952 units on screen. That is normal if you save square pixels and you use a non-projection aware viewer. Also a projection-aware viewer like QGIS shows the image as flattened if the CRS of the project is EPSG:4326. QGIS shows the image with natural looking dimensions if the project is set to use some projected coordinate system, like a suitable UTM zone.

Comment: Thanks for answer @user30184. Yes, I'm looking the image with a non-geospatial viewer (Preview app of Mac). That means, Is that because converting from 32654 to 4326 changes the coordinate system from utm to latlng, and is it correct to distort the appearance?

Comment: If height and width of the pixels is the same in degrees then non-geospatial viewer shows the image that way. If you want non-geospatial viewer to show the image with natural appearance then the height and width of pixels in degrees must be different. How much depends on the latitude. What you experience is actually this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection.

Comment: (Sorry for the late reply.) @user30184 I see, I'll try to consider of another way, as it seems difficult. The projection coordinate system in EPSG:4326 is latlng (or none?) I thought it was, but is it wrong, is it exactly equirectangular projection?

Comment: I do not really know what are the correct names, but I think that equirectangular means here the map projection, how the map in presented on paper or on the screen, and there is no conflict with data being in the EPSG:4326 coordinate system.

Comment: I see, it's all clear now. Thank you very much!